# onChange() Example for sikuli

Tags: sikuli

I'm trying to code the following behaviour into a sikuli script and can't seem to figure it out, even with the documentation.

I want to find something on the screen (this is actually text) then perform a keystroke action when the text to the right changes. I've been looking at `find().right()` to define a region as well as `onChange()` and `observer()`; but don't really understand the documentation properly in order to put them together.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you're using Sikuli IDE and writting in jython.

First, try to use a smaller region as `find().right()` will create a region that is somehow large (extends till the end of the screen), it might help if you specified smaller dimensions for the newly created region to decrease the calculating power when using an observer.

Second, specify the scan rate needed for your observer (also affects efficiency and calculating power needed), it is a setting at the beginning of the script defines how many scans per second are performed on the region observed. the line of code goes like:  `Settings.ObserveScanRate = 10` , this will do 10 scans per second.

Then, you write the two lines of code to start the observer which are for example:
`reg.onChange(50,onchangedFunction)` and `reg.observe(10,background=False)`

For `reg.onchange(50,onchangedFunction)` 50 is the number of pixels that when changed, the function `onchangedFunction` will be implemented.,( 50 is the smallest number possible, you might want to use it as you are detecting change in text)

For `reg.observe(10,background=False)`, here you start observing the region for any change to detect, 10 is the number of seconds that the system will be observing the region , and the second argument is true or false, whether you want the scanning to run in the `background(true)` or for the code to stop until scanning is over (false).

then you need to implement the function `onchangedFunction` (this is just a name), it might go like this:

```
def onchangedFunction(event):
        click(img) #and the rest of the algorithm to be implemented on change
```

but take care as the implementation of the function should be before using it by `reg.onchange()` and in a scope that allows it to be called.

Finally call the `reg.stopObserver()`

I think you code should be something like this:

```
Settings.ObserveScanRate = 10
def onchangedFunction(event):
            click(img2)
reg= Region(find(img1).right())
reg.onChange(50,onchangedFunction)
reg.observe(10,background=False)
reg.stopObserver()
```

Comment: OK, I was on the right tracks with what I had coded previously. However, I get a `ClassCastException` when coding a minimal working example as per your example: `[error] java.lang.ClassCastException ( java.lang.ClassCastException: org.python.core.PyFunction cannot be cast to org.sikuli.script.SikuliEventObserver )`. This occurs at the line invoking `onChange()`.

Comment: @NathanS.Watson-Haigh this is because the return value of find() is a match not a region object. this can be solved simply by replacing     reg=find(img1).right()     with     reg= Region(find(img1).right())